# How to create different build variants pointing to different Servers?

Tags: android, gradle

I am using gradle.build for auto building my app. I want to generate three different APK's each pointing to different Service URL's.

How can I make use of buildVariants (productFlavors in gradle). But I'm not able to figure out where to set the three URL's in the Gradle.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really easy to do with gradle.

```
productFlavors {
    first_server {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"https://first_server_url/\""
    }
    second_server {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"https://second_server_url/\""
    }
}
```

You may want to find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html).

So later you can easy access this variable by `BuildConfig.SERVER_URL`

Answer (score 3):

You can use as like following,

In Gradle:

```
productFlavors{
        serverone {
            applicationId "com.example.krishna.mysample.serverone"
            version 1.1
        }

        servertwo {
            applicationId "com.example.krishna.mysample.servertwo"
            version 1.1
        }
        serverthree {
            applicationId "com.example.krishna.mysample.serverthree"
            version 1.1
        }
    }
```

In folder structure In App:

```
src
  -->main
  -->serverone
  -->servertwo
  -->serverthree
```

If MainActivity is required to `different logic` then, that MainActivity is place in serverone, servertwo and serverthree folder `remaining classes are keep in main folder` only. And do diffent functionality on that Activities.